# windows 7 wireless knocks off other computers on the network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, limited-access

I am trying to fix a wireless network issue. When a new windows 7 machine (we have 2 in the house) we have problems with any other windows xp machines connecting to the wireless network. I am using a linksys WRT110 running Firmware Version: 1.0.04 (which is not the latest firmware its Ver.1.0.07 but the router would not use the bin update file). 
I have tried a ton of variations in setting for the wireless network, changed the channel, the security level (none, wep wpa, wpa2), network type (g,bg mixed). I have also read some stuff about homegroup settings for windows 7 but have not seen any differences that make a difference.

Basically windows 7 does not like to connect to our network but when I manage to get it to work the windows xp pro machines get kicked off.

The windows xp pro machines are a few years old but both windows 7 machines are less than 6 months old.

Comment: Any messages when the XP machines lose connectivity?

Comment: no unfortunately when xp get kicked off there is no message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this:
http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/wrt110-windows-7-compatibility/m-p/301759

let me know if it works: husband has the offending laptop at work so I can't verify right now.

Comment: seems to be working